# Git - merge non-git changes

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I've got a remote code-base in TFS and am maintaining changes locally in git.  I have two git repositories, my working tree and a backup tree.  I've been making changes to my working tree and merging them to the backup tree.  Now I need to merge changes from TFS into my git repository and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to merge correctly.  I've got this:

```
TFS-----------------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+-->
                 \                              \
git working       ---+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+---->
                  \      \     \              \
git backup         -----------------------------  ?

(+ = commit, \ = merge)
```

So currently I have my two git repositories containing all the changes I've made locally.  Then I've got the latest version from TFS which has overwritten my local changes in my working tree, but I've not yet committed that to the git repository.

So I think what I want to do is to commit the TFS changes to the working tree and then merge that to the backup tree as though it was a separate branch?  Or am I better of branching the initial git version, adding the TFS changes to that and then merging the two branches?

Any suggestions on how to do this well are appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to parse your question, and I wonder if you could clarify a couple of things. (a) is "TFS" a non-git or non-version controlled source? (for example a zip or tar-ball downloaded from sourceforce)  (b) when you say "tree" are you referring to a "branch" in git-ese? (c) when you "get the latest version from TFS" is that the equivalent of extracting said tar-ball and overwriting your working directory? (or work tree in git-ese)?

Comment: TFS is a non-git version-controlled source (Team Foundation Server). By tree, I mean git repository - so I push and pull between them.

Comment: Have you considered making a repo containing only the TFS original code, so when you add updates, GIT can work out the deltas. Merging is easy once you have that, because it can apply those delta's to your working tree when you pull from the repo containing the TFS code.

Comment: This does assume you seed the TFS repo with the contents of your working tree (or backup tree) from before you started making changes

Comment: Yes, I think it's a bit late for that strategy now. But wouldn't making a branch from the original git commit have the same effect?

Comment: yes it would.   "git checkout -b TFS <original-commit-id>",  unpack new TFS over existing TFS, "git commit -a -m TFS-rel-2".  Then checkout your working branch and merge from TFS.